# Confusion about default search vs. constrained search

Tags: support, search

I'm currently writing my Master Thesis in Computer Science and would like to briefly mention the impact of Stackoverflow.com on a developer's workflow. Additionally I'd like to point the popularity of different technologies by looking at the amount of questions tagged with each.

Having used the search engine, I'm a little bit confused about its results. In my case I want everything tagged with "xamarin" (A Crossplatform Framework), hence I'll start a search with `[xamarin]` as parameter. Turned out there are *4600* questions currently tagged. Next, I want to narrow that search by excluding old questions, so I'll start another one with the parameters `[xamarin] created: 2013..2014`. This query should filter the 4600 results, showing only those questions, that were created between 01.01.2013 and 31.12.2014. The result for this query are **9121** questions, however, so more than my unconstrained search.

Did I miss anything? Is the unconstrained search already filtering something by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When searching on tags only questions are returned.

The additional parameter causes answers to be returned as well, so you will want to constrain further:

```
[xamarin] created:2013..2014 is:question
```

[That will return ~4,400 posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bxamarin%5D%20created%3A2013..2014%20is%3Aquestion).

Comment: Thanks, that explains the difference ! :)